# Numpy elementwise multiplication (unexpected integer overflow)

Tags: python, numpy, elementwise-operations

I'm using Python 3.7 and numpy 1.15.2 and have encountered a behavior in elementwise multiplication that I don't understand. The following is intuitive to me:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[30000,4000]])
b = np.array([[70000,8000]])
np.multiply(a,b)
```

gives

```
array([[2100000000,32000000]])
```

However, when I do

```
a = np.array([[30000,40000]])
b = np.array([[70000,80000]])
np.multiply(a,b)
```

I get

```
array([[ 2100000000, -1094967296]])
```

I would have guessed that the result should be array([[ 30000*70000, 40000*80000]]). Where does the negative number come from? And what should I do to get the expected array?

Comment: This is not "unintuitive", this is how numbers are being represented on computers. This [wikipedia article on data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type#Numeric_types) may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like numpy by default interprets plain numbers as `np.int32` (which has a range from -2<sup>31</sup> ... 2<sup>31</sup> - 1), which will overflow with `40000*80000`, because `3200000000 > 2**31 - 1 (= 2147483647)`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[30000,40000]])
b = np.array([[70000,80000]])
np.multiply(a,b)
Out: array([[ 2100000000, -1094967296]])

type(a[0][0])
Out: numpy.int32
```

You can solve this by explicitely setting a better suited data type:

```
a = np.array([[30000,40000]], dtype=np.int64)
b = np.array([[70000,80000]], dtype=np.int64)
np.multiply(a,b)
Out: array([[2100000000, 3200000000]], dtype=int64)
```

or

```
a = np.array([[30000,40000]], dtype=np.uint32)
b = np.array([[70000,80000]], dtype=np.uint32)
np.multiply(a,b)
Out: array([[2100000000, 3200000000]], dtype=uint32)
```